# Как получить HTML код полностью загруженной страницы в C#

Tags: c#, парсер

В ходе создания своего парсера сайтов столкнулся с проблемой. С помощью http запроса пытался получить HTML код страницы, чтобы взять нужные данные, но код который я получил отличается от кода в браузере. Я узнал что есть сайты с динамической загрузкой контента, где данные догружаются с помощью запросов осуществляемых на JavaScript. Во время поиска решения этой проблемы наткнулся на вопрос на StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130650/scraping-data-dynamically-generated-by-javascript-in-html-document-using-c-sharp   где для решения этой проблемы предлагалось использовать так называемый WebBrowser, который сможет загрузить страницу, где выполнится весь необходимый код, а затем запросить её HTML код. Проблема в том, что я нигде не могу найти этот класс WebBrowser, скачивал несколько библиотек, но всё тщетно. Если вы знаете где его найти, то подскажите.

Comment: Любой сайт имеет уникальную структуру, под которую надо писать персональный код. Универсальной отмычки в мире не существует, да вы можете автоматизировать работу полноценного браузера, чтоб тот что-то кликал и делал за вас, но смысл в чем? Будет у вас медленный парсер, требующий кучу RAM, и тонну всего лишнего, когда могли разобрать сайт и отправить запросы напрямую. Вот случай из жизни - сделал бота для браузерной игры, просто раз в пару мин заходил и отправлял запросы. На днях сайт "помер", но API работали, все не могли играть, а мой бот продолжал выполнять задачу.

Comment: Так что, подумайте очень хорошо, нужна-ли вам эта мифическая универсальность, или всеж начнете понимать структуру сайтов, как они работают, и работать уже с ними, минуя UI? Ну а что касается браузера - WebBrowser уже очень давно устарел, используйте что-то современное, к примеру WebView2, ну или если нужна автоматизация, то Selenium.